# How do I use Regex.Replace to replace two dots?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find in a string a pattern with two dots (..) e.g.:

Example 1:

```
axdb..TXU
```

and replace it with

```
TXU@axdb_LNK
```

another example would be e.g.:

Example 2

```
ssrrdb..WOPXLP
```

and replace it with

```
WOPXLP@ssrrdb_LNK
```

It could occur once or many times in the string and there could be any number of letters before or after the double dots.  Also, there will be other text in the string. e.g:

```
SELECT col2 FROM axdb..TXU a WHERE a.col1 = 1 
(could also be select * from axdb..TXU )
```

would be changed to

```
SELECT col2 FROM TXU@axdb_LNK a WHERE a.col1 = 1 
(could also be select * from TXU@axdb_LNK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(\S+)\.\.(\S+)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Sample code

```
///<summary>  
///
///  [1]: A numbered capture group. [\S+]
///      Anything other than whitespace, one or more repetitions
///  \.\.
///      Literal .
///      Literal .
///  [2]: A numbered capture group. [\S+]
///      Anything other than whitespace, one or more repetitions
///
///  
///
/// </summary>
public Regex MyRegex = new Regex(
            "(\\S+)\\.\\.(\\S+)",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
            | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
            | RegexOptions.Compiled
            );

// This is the replacement string
public string MyRegexReplace = "$2@$1_LNK";

//// Replace the matched text in the InputText using the replacement pattern
string result = MyRegex.Replace(InputText,MyRegexReplace);
```

Comment: Alex, your example returns:
    TXU@SELECT col2 FROM axdb_LNK a WHERE a.col1 = 1

.  What I would need is:
    SELECT col2 FROM TXU@axdb_LNK a WHERE a.col1 = 1

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED:Consider the following code snippet...

```
string inputMessage = @"SELECT col2 FROM axdb..TXU a WHERE a.col1 = 1 
(could also be select * from axdb..TXU )";
var match = Regex.Match(inputMessage, @"(?<1>\w*)\.\.(?<2>\w*)");
string outputMessage = inputMessage.Replace(match.Value, string.Format("{2}@{1}_LNK", match.Groups[0].Value, match.Groups[1].Value));
```

Good Luck!

Comment: The OP is attempting to replace parts of a larger string, not just reformat `axdb..TXU`

Comment: @Paqogomez...If I were to summarize what LALLB is asking it is as follows: "I need to find in a string a pattern...and replace it with..." Please advise if you have different take on it.

Comment: He says that `SELECT ...` **will be changed to** `SELECT...`.  I think that bit is what makes it clear that he needs to keep everything on the string

Comment: perhaps, all you need is to then replace `inputmessage` with `outputmessage` in the original string.

Comment: hmmm.. wouldnt it be `string.Format("{1}@{0}_LNK` ?

Comment: Unfortunately gpmurthy,  that doesn't work either, it returns the replace string with "...  axdb@axdb..TXU_LNK  ..."  this should be:
"...  TXU@axdb_LNK  ..."

Comment: That didn't work either.  it dropped off everything in the brackets (could also ... ), but also returned "...  axdb_LNK  ..." when it should be TXU@axdb_LNK